# Creating Layout service url for Sitecore Jss multisite application in azure

Tags: jss

I am completely new to Sitecore Jss. i am trying to implement a multisite sitecore application using jss. I already have a jss site hosted in azure with layout service "https://abc.org/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={my api key}".

Now I want to create another layout service url for my site 2. For that I have followed below steps till now,

1. Created a new API key in sitecore.
2. An SSL binding with name "https://def.org" is created against the existing app service.
3. Created an empty site item in sitecore and added a patch with above site name as the host name in Sitecore.config

But when I am trying to access [https://def.org/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={my](https://def.org/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=%7Bmy) new api key} I am getting "***This site can’t be reached***" error. Is there anything I am missing out here ?

I tried the same steps in my local (insted of azure added the binding in IIS) and it worked. Please let me know if anyone can think of something.

Thanks,
Rashmi